# Comparing arrays of objects with arrays of fields of objects

Tags: c++

Is there a good way to compare arr[i].A to A[i] and arr[i].B to B?

```
int A[10], B[10];

class Foo {
   int A, B;
};

Foo arr[10];
```

I could do the following:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
   if (A[i] == arr[i].A) {}
   if (B[i] == arr[i].B) {}
}
```

But, this is painful especially if there are a lot of fields, and the if() conditional does the same thing over and over, there will be a lot of code duplication. What I really want to do is parametrize this somehow and call a function like (test(A,arr)). I guess I can solve this by using #define macros, but that seems ugly.

Any suggestions?

Also I want to avoid creating a new array of Foo objects because I don't want to create new objects that may have many fields I don't care about, also I may want to compare different subsets of fields.

Comment: `A[i]` is a single int whereas `arr[i].A` is an array of 10 ints. Are you wanting to compare each `A[i]` to each element within `arr[i].A`?

Comment: `A[i]` isn't the same type as `arr[i].A`.  The former is `int`, the latter is `int[10]`. Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: Oops. That's correct. I edited the question to what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the ranges are of equal size you can use std::equal with a predicate (or a lambda):

```
bool CompA( int lhs, Foo rhs ){
   return lhs == rhs.A;
};
...
// to check for equality
bool result = std::equal( A, A + 10, arr, CompA );
...
// to see where the mismatch is
std::pair< int*, Foo* > result = std::mismatch( A, A + 10, arr, CompA );
size_t index = result.first - A;
if( index < 10 ){
   std::cout << "Mismatch at index " << index << " A = " << *result.first << " Foo.A = " << (*result.second).A << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Cool. This works for me, except for one thing. I also want to know which index didn't match.

Answer (score 1):

There are standard-library algorithms for doing operations on containers (including arrays, kinda) but using them typically produces code that's harder to read and maintain, and no shorter or more efficient, than straightforward loops.

However, it sounds as if you might want to know about pointers-to-members.

```
bool all_equal(int Foo::* member, const Foo * obj_array, const int * elem_array, size_t n) {
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    if (obj_array[i].*member != elem_array[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

...

if (all_equal(&Foo::A, arr, A, 10) && all_equal(&Foo::*B, arr, B, 10)) ...
```

although actually you should probably generalize it:

```
template<typename T, typename E>
bool all_equal(E T::* member, const T* obj_array, const E* elem_array, size_t n) {
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    if (obj_array[i].*member != elem_array[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

(Danger: all code above is untested and may consist entirely of bugs.)

Comment: Oooh. Nice. Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Fixed a couple of typos (edited above), and the code works great. Thanks!